# How do I add callbacks when using the devise-guests gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

From looking at the [code](https://github.com/cbeer/devise-guests/blob/master/lib/devise-guests/controllers/helpers.rb), it looks as though I should be able to add a logging_in_user callback when using the [devise-guests](https://github.com/cbeer/devise-guests) gem. How and where should the callback be added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an example controller [here](https://github.com/alvinlee1/blacklight/blob/6a24cfcbf1657bdaa388a1e76453220410423db8/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/blacklight-4.0.0/lib/blacklight/controller.rb)

In your ApplicationController you need to define and then set the callback like so:

```
define_callbacks :logging_in_user
set_callback :logging_in_user, :before, :transfer_guest_user_actions_to_current_user

def transfer_guest_user_actions_to_current_user
  # todo
end
```